# Laptop lid power options

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, external-monitor, headless

How do I configure my laptop to perform in the following manner in Ubuntu 14.04.1 Server?

**Current State**
When the laptop is powered on and the lid is closed:
External screen loses signal
Laptop enters suspended state
Upon reboot, laptop displays to internal screen

**Preferred State**
When the laptop is powered on and the lid is closed:
Laptop sustains signal to external screen - SOLVED
Internal screen powers off
Laptop does not enter suspended state - SOLVED
Upon reboot, preferred state is maintained and laptop displays to external screen (including POST and BIOS) - SOLVED

Thank you for your help

Note: To alleviate possible BIOS questions, the machine is a Dell Latitude E5400 with updated BIOS (rev A17)

Answer (score 1):

Open the `logind.conf` file

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Changed the following line:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Laptop lid no longer dictates suspend mode and configuration saves after reboot. This solves all problems save one:
I prefer the internal screen powered off when laptop lid is closed while sustaining signal to the external screen.